# How to emplement the multiple select of recipients emails in a text box like in Gmail in .net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

[This is my modal and I want to emplement the multiple select email of recipients like gmail have using asp.net mvc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Q3X.png)

[Exact like this SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEdLi.png)

[And when I click any where under the modal the emails should be like this, shown in 3rd photo link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFdH8.png)

[See like stackoverflow have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g6sQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a plugin in the front end like [Select2](https://select2.org/tagging), I think is the fastest way, I’ve used it

Comment: Thanks for answer, their is the thing exact I want but I was unable to use it in razor page with extention .cshtml. Can you please share working code snippet!?

Comment: It's kind of a bigger thing you need than just a simple code snippet to implement!, but to give you a general idea: you just have to Include the Stylesheet of Select2, the JS of Select2 and pass the variables with a ViewBag array (server side) and fill with that data the parameters used by Select2 at the constructor. 

Maybe this example can help you: https://www.yogihosting.com/select2-jquery-plugin-aspnet-core/

Comment: Thank you so much, again!... Really it worked and I can't explain how much happy I was now thank you very very much, appreciate your work man. @benjamingranados